# Assignment makes pointer from int w/out a cast

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, casting, integer

I am compiling some code for a program that memoizes fibonacci numbers. The program works perfectly however when I compile in linux environment I get this warning before compiling.

```
line 61: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Here is a snippet of code of where this warning is coming from, I'll try to show things of most relevance to get the best picture presented of the situation

```
int InitializeFunction(intStruct *p, int n)

    p->digits = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);

        if(p->digits == NULL)
            handleError("Got error");

    //making the one index in p->digits equal to n
    p->digits[0] = n;

    //incrementing a field of 'p'
    p->length++;

    //return 1 if successful
    return 1;
```

This function is only called twice for a very specific purpose. it is used to initialize the two base cases in the fibonacci sequence f[0] = 0 & f[1] = 1. That's it's only purpose. So if I pass by reference the address of a specific index in an array of structs it's just supposed to initialize those values:

```
Initializer(&someIntStruct[0], 0) ---->  after function -> someIntStruct[0] == 0
Initializer(&someIntStruct[1], 1) ---->  after function -> someIntStruct[1] == 1
```

thoughts?

Comment: 1/ Don't ever cast the return value from malloc (in C anyway). 2/ Multiplying by one is what's called an identity operation, has no effect, totally unnecessary. 3/ You return 1 _always_ so I'm not sure how you detect failure unless `handleError` exits your program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
p->digits = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
```

to

```
p->digits = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
```

Comment: _Don't_ cast malloc in C at all, you're just _asking_ for trouble.

Comment: @paxdiablo I've seen the reason in Nobilis 's link, it's helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the warning has to do with this line:

```
p->digits = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
```

Since malloc returns a void* , whereas you are casting it to int. I suppose `p->digits` is an `int*` ?

Try changing it to:

```
p->digits = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

[It's considered bad practice to cast the result of malloc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

And as already pointed out you're not doing it correctly either (should be `(int*)` ).