# compare strings after converting to lower case in c

Tags: c, strcmp, tolower

I need to compare two strings for equality (case-insensitive) but my implementation is returning alot of warnings at compile.

my implementation:

```
//The word array will contain any number of strings of varying lengths
//string is the word to compare to
char **wordArray, char*string;

int i, sizeOfArray = 10

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    //Return 1 if the string is seen in the array 
    if(strcmp(tolower(wordArray[i]), tolower(string)) == 0)
        return 1;
}

return 0;
```

I'm getting these warnings:

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘tolower’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’

initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

How can i implement this

Comment: You should read the documentation of `tolower()`.

Comment: `tolower` processes single character

Answer (score 5):

`tolower` doesn't make a whole string lowercase, just a single character.  You need to put it in a loop to do what you're trying.

Your system may have a [`strcasecmp(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcasecmp/) (UNIXy) or [`_stricmp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (windows) function, which would be more convenient for you (though non-standard).

`strcasecmp` *is* in POSIX, so it's likely to be quite portable, should you choose that route.

Comment: I was planning to downvote the answers with a comment syaing "this question should be closed and not answered", but I throw away the downvoting part since it was you answering...

Comment: Is it a duplicate?  Otherwise it seems like a reasonable enough question; especially since the right answer isn't "read the `tolower` docs", it's "use a case-insensitive string comparison".

Comment: Conversely, +1 because someone downvoted :P (Blehh, changin' my mind...)

Comment: why so? If he had read it, he would have found out that `tolower()` is for converting a single character. Making assumptions instead of referring the documentation is not "reasonable enough".

Comment: Sure, but that would just have led him to solve the problem in the wrong way. If his question was worded "is there a case-insensitive string comparison function", would that be better?  That's the subtext here.

Comment: Yes, that's right. By the way, he posted a question about a very similar error, just the other way around (the message did not say "integer from pointer", but "pointer from integer"): [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182041/assignment-makes-pointer-from-int-w-out-a-cast). Apparently, he hasn't learnt anything from the solution/answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `stricmp(wordArray[i],string)`

instead of `strcmp(tolower(wordArray[i]), tolower(string))`